# Contact Form doesn't send mail

Tags: php, html

I have a problem. Today I made contact form but it is not sending any emails and I don't know why. I downloaded an free example and I tried to add it to my own site but it's not working, any ideas? Here is the code:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="wniosek" action="wyslijWniosek.php" method="POST">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="firma rel col-sm-12"><span class="inp"><input name="firma" type="text" placeholder="Nazwa Firmy" class="col-sm-12"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="name rel col-sm-12"><span class="inp"><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Imie i nazwisko" class="col-sm-12"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="phone rel col-sm-12"><span class="inp"><input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Telefon" class="col-sm-12"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="email rel col-sm-12"><span class="inp"><input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="col-sm-12"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="kwota rel col-sm-12"><span class="inp"><input name="kwota" type="text" placeholder="Prognozowana Kwota" class="col-sm-12"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="wnio col-sm-12">
            <select name="wnio" style="width:100%;">
                <option value="kfirm">Kredyt Firmowy</option>
                <option value="kgot">Kredyt Gotówkowy</option>
                <option value="kobro">Kredyt Obrotowy</option>
                <option value="phipo">Pozyczka Hipoteczna</option>
                <option value="khipo">Kredyt Hipoteczny</option>
                <option value="kkonso">Kredyt Konsolidacyjny</option>
                <option value="kinwest">Kredyt Inwestycyjny</option>
                <option value="ksamocho">Kredyt Samochodowy</option>
                <option value="leasing">Leasing</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label class="message rel col-sm-12"><span class="text_a"><textarea name="message" class="col-sm-12" placeholder="Wiadomosc" style="height:300px;"></textarea></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="buttons-wrapper">
            <input class="button2 btn btn-white" type="submit" value="Send">
            <input class="button2 btn btn-white" type="reset" value="Clear">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and php:

```
<?php
$firma = $_POST['firma'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$wnio = $_POST['wnio'];
$kwota = $_POST['kwota'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" Nazwa Firmy: $firma \n Imie i Nazwisko: $name \n Email: $email \n Telefon: $phone \n Wniosek: $wnio \n Prognozowana Kwota: $kwota \n Wiadomość: $message";
$recipient = "<mail here>";
$subject = "Formularz Kontaktowy";
$mailheader = "Wiadomość ze strony internetowej";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Błąd!");
echo "Dziękujemy!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

where is mail here i put my own email

Comment: In what way is it not working? Does it display any error? Does the mail simply fail to arrive?

Comment: are you testing in a localhost?

Comment: It does not display any error and mail fail to arrive

Comment: i did put it on server

Comment: what's that on your mail header? you need at the very least a 'from' header.

Comment: Now my mail header look like $mailheader = "Od: $email \r\n"; and still its not working

Comment: I think you should not translate `From`

Comment: still not working :P

Comment: Is the mail maybe delivered in a spam box?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Błąd!");` with below code.

```
$suc = mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
if($suc){//If success
   print_r("No error");        
}
else{//If error on mail send
   print_r(error_get_last());
}
exit();//Remove this after debugging done
```

If `mail()` not delivered successfully this code will print error into array format, else it would print **'No error'**.

Let us know if you face any further query regarding the same.

Comment: It was working but now it isn't i think i changed something but i don't know what... now my code look like this:

Comment: Can you help it  is not working again, i posted my answer with code

Comment: If your code worked fine then revert my solution code and check once.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the sender e-mail in your header.

```
$mailheader = "From: sender@mail.com";
```

Comment: Now my mail header look like $mailheader = "Od: $email \r\n"; and still its not working